# C++ in Xcode - how can I have multiple inputs used in one line?

Tags: c++, xcode

I've noticed that I can only get one cin to show up per line, but I am trying to get multiple inputs inline.

How would I go about achieving this?

```
int main(){
    int one, two, three;

    cout << "One: ";
    cin >> one;
    cout << "Two: ";
    cin >> two;
    cout << "Three: ";
    cin >> three;
}
```

I'd like them all to appear in one line so say if 1, 5, and 78 were entered, it'd show as

```
    One: 1 Two: 5 Three:78.
```

Instead, Xcode pushes everything down so it comes out as

```
    One: 1
    Two: 5
    Three 78
```

Comment: Please clarify "multiple inputs inline".  Are you using separate files? Separate stream? Are the inputs coming from different hardware sources?  Do you need to confuse the User by interweaving outputs from the different inputs?

Comment: Are you talking about multiple data items on one text line, such as Comma Separated, or Tab separated values (CSV) format?

Comment: If you can, please edit your question with a few sample inputs (and annotate them).

Comment: The issue is not the con The issue is that to end what you read into cout the input stream must end with a carriage return - so you need to use a UI library to control input not just streams